# Unable to load javacv and googlecode in openCV Project

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I am doing facerecognition  in android using openCV but unable to load googlecode and javacv libraries.
Already having javacpp.jar and javacv.jar in

> jniLibs

folder

Also used

> compile 'com.googlecode.javacpp:javacpp:0.7'

in build.gradle.

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rsehdev.opencv"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')

    compile 'com.googlecode.javacpp:javacpp:0.7'
    //compile 'com.googlecode.javacv:javacv:0.7'

}
```